# How to control the number of objects in a Django model

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
# Product Photos       
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    product    = models.ForeignKey("Product", null=False, default="0", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
    file       = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path,
                                    max_length=500,
                                    null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    processors=[ResizeToFill(800, 450)],
                                    options={'quality': 80})
    #height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    #width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see there is a product foreign key. What I want to do is, prevent this photo model from accepting not more than 5 photos from the same product.

Basically, each product should have 5 photos or less.
How can I control this from Photo model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find how many photos in the save method,

```
def __save__(self,**kwargs,*args):
   if product.photos.count()>5
      pass
    else:
        save()
```

The syntax may wrong,but adjust according to your business logic

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `Product` model, add a check for number of `Photos` it has.
While updating the photo of the Product, use this check to ensure no more that 5 photos are uploaded.